# xslt: select all specific node between two nodes but stop at specific node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have to select and apply templates for all specific node between two nodes but stop at specific node.....
for example in this code:

```
.........

<p class="capo">1</p>
<p class="busta">prima</p>
<p class="dialogo1">dati</p>
<p class="dialogo2">dati</p>
<p class="dialogo3">dati</p>
<p class="busta">seconda:</p>
<p class="dialogo4">dati</p>
<p class="dialogo5">dati</p>
<p class="capo">2</p>
<p class="capo">3</p>
<p class="dialogo6">dati</p>
<p class="capo">4</p>
<p class="busta">terza:</p>

..........
```

I need to select  all `<p class="dialogo"/>` between and after tag `<p class="busta"/>`, but if I found a `<p class="capo"/>` I need to stop...
The result must be like this:

```
<busta>
  <p class="dialogo1">dati</p>
  <p class="dialogo2">dati</p>
  <p class="dialogo3">dati</p>
</busta>
<busta>
  <p class="dialogo4">dati</p>
  <p class="dialogo5">dati</p>
</busta> 
..........
```

In `"template match="p[@class='busta']"` I am using following code but selection dont stop when find capo and catch also dialogo 6 `"select="following-sibling::p[@class='busta'] [generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@class='busta'][1]) = generate-id(current())]"/>"`

Thanks in advance

Comment: So can you use XSLT 2 and `for-each-group group-starting-with`? And what exactly has to stop, the complete selection once a `capo` paragraph has been found or only the selection for the preceding `busta` paragraph? Or said otherwise, what happens where you have the `......`?

Comment: thanks for reply, i could use xsl2. I have edited question so i hope it is clearer.
So i need to have in output only following "dialogo" grouped under "busta". tag dialogo from busta to busta but before capo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2 or 3 this is a text book use of `for-each-group group-starting-with="p[@class = 'busta']"` respectively `group-ending-with="p[@class = 'capo']"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="body">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[@class = 'busta']">
              <xsl:if test="self::p[@class = 'busta']">
                  <busta>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[position() gt 1]" group-ending-with="p[@class = 'capo']">
                        <xsl:if test="position() eq 1">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::p[@class = 'capo'])]"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                  </busta>                  
              </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms

```
<body>
<p class="capo">1</p>
<p class="busta">prima</p>
<p class="dialogo1">dati</p>
<p class="dialogo2">dati</p>
<p class="dialogo3">dati</p>
<p class="busta">seconda:</p>
<p class="dialogo4">dati</p>
<p class="dialogo5">dati</p>
<p class="capo">2</p>
<p class="capo">3</p>
<p class="dialogo6">dati</p>
<p class="capo">4</p>
<p class="busta">terza:</p>
</body>
```

into

```
<body>
   <busta>
      <p class="dialogo1">dati</p>
      <p class="dialogo2">dati</p>
      <p class="dialogo3">dati</p>
   </busta>
   <busta>
      <p class="dialogo4">dati</p>
      <p class="dialogo5">dati</p>
   </busta>
   <busta/>
</body>
```

See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2h.

For XSLT 2 you need to spell out the `xsl:mode` as the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To give you an example where the `p` elements are not children of an input element but passed in as a parameter as a sequence of element nodes, here is how that would look (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2h/1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:param name="paragraphs" as="element()*">
        <p class="capo">1</p>
        <p class="busta">prima</p>
        <p class="dialogo1">dati</p>
        <p class="dialogo2">dati</p>
        <p class="dialogo3">dati</p>
        <p class="busta">seconda:</p>
        <p class="dialogo4">dati</p>
        <p class="dialogo5">dati</p>
        <p class="capo">2</p>
        <p class="capo">3</p>
        <p class="dialogo6">dati</p>
        <p class="capo">4</p>
        <p class="busta">terza:</p>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$paragraphs" group-starting-with="p[@class = 'busta']">
          <xsl:if test="self::p[@class = 'busta']">
              <busta>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[position() gt 1]" group-ending-with="p[@class = 'capo']">
                    <xsl:if test="position() eq 1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::p[@class = 'capo'])]"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
              </busta>                  
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So where and how and with which input selection you use that `for-each-group` is up to you, that does not depend on template matching. You could write a template or function taking the sequence of `p` elements as an input parameter and put the `for-each-group` into the template or function body.

Comment: thank you so much, that is very useful. It had great explanations and proofs

Comment: can i directly matching tag "busta" and not add "body" tag and matching this?

Comment: Usually with XML you don't have a list of elements but there is a container element you can match on. The code doing the grouping does not really depend on the template match, that is just an example to put the grouping into the usual context. So how does a minimal but complete sample of your input look, where do you get those `p` elements from?

Comment: thank you very much, this example is very useful to me