# How to wrap specific chunks in a XML document with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <p>One</p>
    <p>Two</p>
    <p>Three</p>
    <p type="start" />
    <p>A</p>
    <p><id>1</id>B</p>
    <p type="end" />
    <p>Four</p>
    <p>Five</p>
    <p type="start" />
    <p>C</p>
    <p><id>3</id>D</p>
    <p type="end" />
    <p>Six</p>
</doc>
```

I need to wrap everything between a `p[@type ='start']` and `p[@type ='end']` element while preserving the rest of the document. Thus the output should be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <p>One</p>
    <p>Two</p>
    <p>Three</p>
    <group>
        <p>A</p>
        <p><id>1</id>B</p>
    </group>
    <p>Four</p>
    <p>Five</p>
    <group>
        <p>C</p>
        <p><id>3</id>D</p>
    </group>
    <p>Six</p>
</doc>
```

On the ground of [xslt: select all specific node between two nodes but stop at specific node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951415/xslt-select-all-specific-node-between-two-nodes-but-stop-at-specific-node) I tried:

```xml
<xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[@type = 'start']">
        <xsl:if test="self::p[@type = 'start']">
        <group>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[position() gt 1]" group-ending-with="p[@type = 'end']">
                <xsl:if test="position() eq 1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::p[@type = 'end'])]" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </group>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately, this completely eliminates everything that is not between a `p[@type ='start']` and `p[@type ='end']` element. Thus, how would I get the same result, but preserver (pass through for other templates) the rest of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xsl:choose` instead of `xsl:if` and do that twice, also only insert the `group` wrapper if both start and end are found:

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[@type = 'start']">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::p[@type = 'start']">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[position() gt 1]" group-ending-with="p[@type = 'end']">                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-group()[last()][self::p[@type = 'end']]">
                        <group>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(position() = last())]"/>
                        </group>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes you have the identity transformation set up as the base template to copy nodes.

Comment: This only returns the `One`, `Two` and `Three` elements, but not the `Four`, `Five` and `Six`.

Comment: @CutúChiqueño, right, see the edit, basically you need to perform the same check, only for the `end` marker, inside of the inner `for-each-group` and only wrap there.